# Load large number of data from sqlite db

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I have more than  10000+ record in database. I want to load it on a table view. It will take 3 to 4 seconds to fetch all data from database and than load it on table view. Is there is more efficient way to increase the response and load the data in a uitableview?
Here is my code for get All Data fro database

```
- (void)getAllData {
    NSString * convertInttoStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowNumber];
    // Getting the database path.
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iandroidquran_database 3.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];
    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"SELECT * FROM qSurahContent WHERE surahID=%@" ,
                                convertInttoStr];


    // Query result
    FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
    while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {
        NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[resultsWithNameLocation intForColumn:@"surahID"]];
        NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"surahContentArabic"]];

        NSLog(@"surahID = %@, surahName = %@",strID, strName);
        [surahId addObject:strID];
        [surahContentArabic addObject:strName];


    }
    [self.tblView reloadData];

    [database close];
}
```

Any solution?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch Data from DB in main Thread as following :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self getAllData];

});
```

This main thread has high priority and will execute faster than ever. So try this one.

Hope it helps..